# AWK Counting - Weird Behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I Have a csv which contains below format

Field 1, Field 2, Success Count, Failure Count

I wrote a awk script to count the sum of Success count and Failure count of Field 2 values. This script seems to work fine. But suddenly it acts strange.
It adds 2 before even start counting. So the result will be two more greater than actual. Below is my script.

```
sed 's/\r//' FileName.csv | grep 'HTTP Requests - POST' | awk -F "," '{failure += $3; success += $4} END {print "HTTP Requests - POST,  Failure : " failure " Success : "success " Total : " success+failure;}'
```

Then I added success to print on execution.
It prints below.

2
9
27

```
sed 's/\r//' FileName.csv | grep 'HTTP Requests - POST' | awk -F "," '{failure += $3; success += $4; print success;} END {print "HTTP Requests - POST,  Failure : " failure " Success : "success " Total : " success+failure;}'
```

Can anyone help ?

---

CSV is looks like below.

```
OPERATOR,HTTP_METHOD,SUCCESS_COUNT,FAILURE_COUNT
CELL_01,HTTP Requests - POST,10,19
CELL_03,HTTP Requests - GET,12,17
CELL_04,HTTP Requests - POST,1,15
CELL_05,HTTP Requests - PUT,16,14
CELL_01,HTTP Requests - DELETE,19,13
CELL_03,HTTP Requests - POST,17,12
CELL_05,HTTP Requests - PUT,11,13
```

sed was used to remove windows line breaks and replace them with linux line breaks. 

Grep was used to filter only POST Requests.

---

According to @glenn's answer below I tried this.
See output below

```
awk -F "," '/\/GET/ { sub(/\r$/,""); failure += $3; success += $4; print failure; print success; print ""; } END  {print "HTTP Requests - POST,  Failure : " failure " Success : "success " Total : " success+failure}' Sandbox.csv
0
2

0
9

0
27
```

Expected Output
`HTTP Requests - POST, Failure : 0 Success :25 Total : 25`

Comment: So you've counted something we can't see and hope we can tell you why the answer's wrong? Please provide all information necessary to help if you want help.

Comment: What else information you need. I provided the CSV Format and the Command. Is there anything else required ? 
What it does is iterate through the csv and provide the sum of third and fourth column which are success count and failure count.

Comment: The CSV would help. And an explanation of why you need to pass it through `sed`. Why you need to pass it through `grep` too - searching for something you didn't mention in the description.

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Please don't put code or data in comments - it is really hard to interpret. Instead, click `edit` under your question and update the question and format the CSV as code by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button.

Comment: Edited the question 
Thanks for the information

Answer (score 1):

You don't need sed and grep when using awk:

```
awk -F "," '
    /POST/ {
        sub(/\r$/,"")
        failure += $3
        success += $4
        print success
    }
    END {print "HTTP Requests - POST,  Failure : " failure " Success : "success " Total : " success+failure}
' FileName.csv
```

Also, it appears that column 3 is success and column 4 is failure, yet you have the variables reversed in your code. Could that account for the strange behaviour?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the awesome guide on awk.
But It still shows one for failure even though the failure count is zero in file.

Comment: It's strange that I tried printing both success and failure with awk on each step. In POST failure start with 1 instead of zero. In GET success starts with 2.

Comment: Edited the question with sample output.

Comment: Is that the output for that very csv?  The numbers don't make ANY sense, if so...  First success there is 10.....

Comment: @buddhika, BenPen's comment is for you. Given the input you posted, what output do you expect?

Comment: Output should look like this  HTTP Requests - POST, Failure : 0 Success :25 Total : 25

Comment: Put that in the question. But... Why? There are failure counts for each POST line. I count 46 (and 28 success).

Comment: I just pasted a sample output. Counts are not exact values. The count is getting one to two differences in a weird way.

Comment: That's what I wonder. As per the output I pasted you see that failure count starts with two. That's why the output is wrong. Is there anything wrong I did while counting or the way I add values to variables. ???

Comment: Your sample input has 3 POST lines. Explain to us how you are supposed to obtain zero failure count from those 3 lines. As far as I can tell, there is no correlation between your input and output.

Comment: Hi glenn. This is a sample output to recreate the sample scenario. Actual strings which I used to filter the content includes special characters such as "/" and "\". I suspect thar this will cause the problem. I can't share those strings due to confidentiality of the task. Anyway I used escape characters correctly. Is there something I should be careful while searching trings with such special characters like slashes ?